# QGIS 3.6 QUICKOSM buildings query CRS with metre untis to create buffer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer, united-kingdom

Using QGIS 3.6.2

I'm running a QUICKOSM query to find residential buildings in Scotland. I want to then put a buffer around them. The query is fine, if a little slow. The only CRS I can get to accurately project them (i.e. not of the african coast or the coast of Cornwall) are OSGB 1936:4277 and WGS 84:4326. Both these have units in degrees and therefore I can't apply a buffer. Other OSGB (27700 and 7405) don't project correctly nor does Pseudo-Mercator (the Project CRS). OTFP is on by default in 3.6.

Does anyone know a CRS for Scotland/UK that had m units?

Comment: 27700 is the correct one, something else must be wrong with the way you are changing the projection

Comment: Make sure you are starting with the correct CRS set in the layer settings, then **reprojecting** the layer into the CRS you want it in. Don't just change the CRS in the layer settings.

Comment: Layer settings showing CRS as 4277. Changed to 27700 by Set Layer CRS. 3.6 has on the fly projection enabled by default so shouldn't have to manually reproject. Unless I'm missing something?